# Tri-X compared with HP5 plus, grain

Tags: film

I have used Tri-X for a long time as my general-purpose 35mm film.  I use it at 400, process in Rodinal (or a clone in fact) 1+25 and using the massive dev chart times (which agree with Kodak's), and print traditionally (so, in particular I'm generally not scanning the film at all).  I print typically on 16x12, image size about 15x10.  I use Rodinal because I'm used to it: I know what the negs are like and I don't have to worry about made-up dev going stale if I don't process any film for a while.

I'm pretty happy with the process.  But I'm *not* happy about the cost: Tri-X has gone up, a lot, in the last few years and it's becoming a major expense.  HP5 (by which I mean HP5 plus) is a good lot cheaper and is obviously a fine film.  So I've tried a few rolls of it, also at 400, in Rodinal at 1+25 for the recommended time.

I'm printing from these films now and the results look mostly good so far.  But it's evident under the grain focuser that the HP5 is *significantly* grainier (larger grain, more obvious grain) than Tri-X: it's probably grainy enough that the difference is noticeable at my normal print size & would be very noticeable in anything bigger.  This is not catastrophic: obviously if I was unhappy with grain I would not be using fairly fast 35mm film, or in fact 35mm at all.  But it does mean I can't just switch to HP5 without knowing that my prints will change, so it's not a simple decision.

(I'd like to use a single film because I can then get used to it.)

So the question is two things:

1. is HP5 just grainier than Tri-X and I need to get used to it and decide knowing that?
2. Rodinal is known for producing somewhat grainy negs: what other dev might I consider which is painless to use (I'd like not to have to do the whole add-time-when-the-dev-is-old thing and it needs good keeping qualities when made up (months)) which might be better?

As an additional question: are there any other films I might consider?  I am looking at a couple of Foma films, but have not got as far as processing them yet, let alone printing.  It would need to be ISO 400 and some good: I typically can't go back and take pictures again if the negs turn out to be rubbish.  The film needs to be reliably available: I don't want to change every year.

Comment: I've souped Fomapan 400 in Ilfotec DD-X, and the grain is quite noticeable – I'm guessing it might be too much in Rodinal. Have you considered Kodak Xtol? Foma also makes a developer that people claim is a clone of Xtol, the Fomadon Excel. That's likely to be cheaper (depending on where you live).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I went through the same process. Both TriX and HP5+ are films with a strong, almost cult-like, following, and reputation of a major brand to back them up.

Foma is cheap (I am based in Czech, the country Foma is made in, so for me it is *very* cheap) - but it is prone to quality issues (mainly scratches) due to the fact it is still manufactured by hand. A risky bet.

Other ISO 400 films - the talk is positive about Bergger and Rollei - do not have the history and brand strength like Kodak or Ilford.

I ended up picking HP5+ due to a number of factors, chiefly because it costs less and loads into tank easier (less fingerprints) than TriX.

As for souping HP5+ I have settled on Rodinal in 1+50 dilution. The development times are acceptably longer than 1+25 (I do not have patience for stand development). In the stronger dilution (1+25) I found the grain too much, even when shooting 120 film. It is best reserved for special circumstances, to be used on purpose.

I have also found classical grain Ilford films (mainly FP4 though) to respond well to Pyro developers. Good option for static subjects, not so much for fast action - where HP5+ shines. It also responds well to pushing, just like TriX.

To sum it up: if you are looking for a reliable ASA 400 alternative to TriX the HP5+ is likely your best choice.

Consider other developers though, or at the very least go down in dilution from 1+25 to 1+50.

Comment: Thanks, it had not occurred to me that using Rodinal at 1+50 would result in smaller grain.  I've also now got dry prints from HP5+ and I don't think the grain is really a problem in fact.

Comment: @tfb you are welcome! For some reason grain and ISO 400 films go together, and it needs not be a real problem, especially in traditional printing (scanning is different, can't tell exactly why) - I recall coming across a guy on one of the photo forums, who had a signature line "Grain - it is supposed to be there." and I fully agreed with him :)

Answer (score 2):

Tri-X and HP5 are similar films and oftentimes compared. A consensus on which of the two is grainier however seems absent. This may be due to both films having a different grain structure.

I would advise you to play with developing times and dilutions to see what suits you. As you mention yourself, Rodinal is a developer keen for grain and you will see this in your negatives. If you find your HP5+ negs to be too grainy, consider Ilfotec as a substitute for finer grain.

Keep in mind that this all boils down to personal taste. I, for example, am a fan of Ilford's FP4+. It's great in contrast which suits my needs.

Comment: Thanks.  I like FP4+ as well, but as I often use a yellow filter it ends up too slow for me.  I probably do need to bite the bullet and try some other devs.